# Nested lists, dynamic menu: creating a Next Page button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to make a next section button for this html5 app navigation.  It has some nested lists and several pages, each with several slides of content.  When you reach the last slide of a page, I wanted a next section button to be visible, when clicked, goes to the next available page in the menu.

The tricky part is I have a configuration page that allows users to show/hide sections in the navigation, it assigns the **li** section a style="display:none;" when turned off.

So that next button can't simply go to the next page, it has to first make sure its not turned off.

Example of menu:

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <li id="aboutUs"><a href="#">Introduction</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="about-intro.html"><em>00</em>Intro</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-5star.html"><em>01</em>What makes a 5-Star Specialist?</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-install.html"><em>02</em>Installed services</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-products.html"><em>03</em>Our Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-warranty.html"><em>04</em>Our Warranty</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-why-velux.html"><em>05</em>Why VELUX?</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </li>
    <li id="whyAdd" class="prodSkylights"><a href="#">Why skylights?</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Why add a skylight?</a>
                <ul class="sub2-menu">
                    <li><a href="whyadd-daylight.html"><em>01</em>Daylight control & natural light</a></li>
                    <li><a href="whyadd-fresh-air.html"><em>02</em>Fresh air</a></li>
                    <li><a href="whyadd-rooms.html"><em>03</em>Rooms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="whyadd-desirable.html"><em>04</em>Skylights are desirable</a></li>
                    <li class="prodSunTunnel"><a href="whyadd-suntunnels.html"><em>05</em>SUN TUNNELS for small spaces</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Why replace a skylight?</a>
                <ul class="sub2-menu">
                    <li class="prodSkylights"><a href="whyreplace-skylights.html"><em>01</em>Why replace when reroofing?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="whyreplace-upgrade.html"><em>02</em>Upgrade from plastic to glass</a></li>
                    <li><a href="whyreplace-installation.html"><em>03</em>Easy installation</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>  
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="vss" class="prodSkylights"><a href="#">Solar Powered "Fresh Air" Skylight</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="vss-why.html"><em>01</em>Why fresh air skylights?</a></li>
            <li><a href="vss-skylight.html"><em>02</em>Solar Powered "Fresh Air" Skylight</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I make this button happen?

I wanted something like:

```
$("#next-section").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();         // cancel click through
    // get current list item
    var currli = $('li:visible a');
    // get next list item
    var nextli = currli.next();
    // if nextli length is 0, make it equal to first li
    if (nextli.length == 0) {
        nextli = currli.siblings(':first');
    }
    var nextpage = nextli.attr('href');

    window.location = nextpage;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var currli = $('li:visible');
```

This will not select the "current" list item for the page that you are on; this will select all list items that are currently visible. You also have to remember that this will select **all list items**, which will also include your most outer "list sections".

From my understanding, this HTML menu example will be on all of the pages whose URLs are in the most embedded `li` elements. If that's the case, I would assign some class to the "active" list item for the current page. So I would assign something like `class="active"` to the list item whose page I am on.

Then, you can select the "current" list item by doing something like:

```
var currLi = $('li.active');
```

Here's the tricky part: since your HTML isn't consistent (you could have multiple sub-menus to reach the actual list items), you need to figure out a way to "jump over" to the next section, if need be. You can tell if you need to go to the next section by using the `:last-child` selector like this:

```
var nextPage = null;
if (currLi.is(':last-child')) {
    // we need to jump the gap
    var nextSubmenu = null;
    var parentUl = currLi.parent('ul');
    // check to see if we're in a 2 layer submenu and we need to get to the next
    var isSubmenu = parentUl.hasClass('sub2-menu');
    if (isSubmenu && parentUl.parent('li').is(':first-child')) {
        nextSubmenu = parentUl.parent('li').nextAll('li:visible')
            .eq(0).children('ul.sub2-menu');
    }
    else {
        if (isSubmenu) {
            parentUl = parentUl.closest('ul.sub-menu');    
        }
        nextSubmenu = parentUl.parent('li')
            .nextAll('li:visible').eq(0).children('ul.sub-menu');
        // check to see if there are sub layers here
        var sub2Menu = nextSubmenu.find('ul.sub2-menu');
        if (sub2Menu.length > 0) {
            nextSubmenu = sub2Menu.eq(0);
        }
    }
    nextPage = nextSubmenu.find('li:first-child > a').attr('href');
}
else {
    nextPage = currLi.next('li').children('a').attr('href');
}
// finally, navigate!
window.location = nextPage;
```

Phew! Maybe now you will see the problem with multiple embedded elements with no classes? Of course, this code would be much simpler if you placed a few classes on the elements which would allow you to get directly select the elements you want without all this guess-work.

Comment: I will test this, I actually do use an "active" class to mark which page I am on.  The reason I had put inconsistent classes on li elements was to help with the menu filtering.  I can filter by product types OR by turning li's off or on, themselves.  That is why you see "prodSkylight".  There's probably a better way for that, but it's what is working.

Comment: I think you need 'li a' to find the href? I'm still getting undefined for nextPage

Comment: Yep, I edited that in now. Also fixing an issue with finding out if there are sub layers below. One second.

Comment: Ok, I believe I have tested and fixed all the edge cases that I didn't correctly handle before. One still stands though: you will have to detect and decide what to do when you are at the last link in the whole menu.

Comment: I tested it to go to the next section, but it is skipping the next visible link in its own list.  So intro is going to the next main section instead of the next page contained within its parent section.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Here is a JSFiddle of it working as far as I understand. http://jsfiddle.net/4SJBH/

Comment: I don't think visibility is working, i've even added a class of .inactive that has both visibility:hidden AND display:none;

Comment: I see what you mean. The problem was with the `.next()` method. I misunderstood how it worked. It actually only selects the next sibling if it matches the selector; I thought it would match the next sibling based on the selector. Instead, I am using `.nextAll()` which returns all following elements that match the selector. Here's a JSFiddle that shows it stepping through, skipping over the middle section: http://jsfiddle.net/4SJBH/1/

Comment: This is so close!! Problem i'm having now is while it's properly skipping hidden whole sections, it is not skipping pages that are inactive within the same section: [jsfiddle.net/D6qt7/](http://jsfiddle.net/D6qt7/)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you added an `.inactive` class. How about I challenge you to add that functionality (since this is about learning)? You will need to modify the methods to jump over any items that have the `.inactive` class by using a combination of the [:not() selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and the [.nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) function. Then you must determine if by skipping these, it will cause you to go to the next section.

Comment: Okay, I am trying, I'll do more this weekend to get it working, I thought line 17 was where you are finding the next li in the sub-menu [http://jsfiddle.net/D6qt7/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/D6qt7/6/) I haven't been able to get the :not selector to work there.

Comment: Not exactly. It looks like you're putting the `:not()` selector on the parent `li` element. There probably won't be one "simple solution" where you can just change one line. To get more familiar with "walking the DOM tree", try printing to the console the results from different jQuery selectors. That might help you get a feel for what's going on.

Comment: I think I've got it, I used: nextPageLi = currLi.nextAll('li').not('.inactive').first();  and it seems to be doing the trick.  [http://jsfiddle.net/D6qt7/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/D6qt7/8/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Nate.  I have found one more bug I'm trying to solve, [http://jsfiddle.net/D6qt7/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/D6qt7/10/)  It is when the last-child of a submenu is also inactive, it gets stuck.  I'm trying to figure out how best to fix that part.

Comment: Right. I strongly encourage you to add a unique class name to every `li` element you are trying to "page through". I tried to do my best with what your structure currently provided, but it would be silly to continue using such a volatile and complex method. Here is an example of what you can do when you simply add a unique class name on every element: http://jsfiddle.net/D6qt7/11/

Comment: Awesome, I went ahead and used that method, it's much easier.  I had to do a few things to my filtering options and be sure to append ".inactive" to all children to sections the user will disable but it works great.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:visible` selector to choose only elements that are visible.
https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/